# LESS.JS decide where to compile to with multiple files

Tags: less

I have a few .less files and I'm using less app to compile them all, the structure I use is roughly (using less 1.4):

--mixins.less -  this file includes all the mixins.

--color-scheme.less - this file includes all classes that has any color reference.

--main.less - the rest of the site's styles, this @imports both mixins.less and color-scheme.less

In main.less I'm using a `++.className` syntax that compiles all the classes using it to a list with only 1 declaration, so:

```
.foo{
    color:red
}
.bar{
    ++.foo;
}
.fiz{
    ++.foo;
}
```

compile to:

```
.foo, .bar, .fiz{
    color:red;
}
```

this is compiled at the top of main.css (the output of main.less) and since I have a few color themes I need to manually compile each time there's a change and manually separate the the declarations with colors to a different file..

Basically I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to compile all the classes which use the ++ to a specific file.

thanks!

Comment: I am the one who originally suggested the `++` syntax.  And I just want you to know that the syntax has since been changed and approved to use a more CSS-like `:extends(.selector)`.  To answer your question though, you would need to modify the LESS compiler to do what you want.

Comment: @RyanWheale thanks for your answer. this new syntax - which version is it used on? I currently have quite a big code base already using the ++ syntax.. by the way, it looked like the compiler had some errors compiling a nested ++ syntax when using a nested &:. ping me if you want some examples. thanks again!

Comment: Well, the thing is, the `++` syntax never really made it very far.  You must of grabbed a version which existed for only a couple weeks.  The new (better) syntax is the `:extend()` method I mentioned above.  It is unlikely you are going to get any support of a feature that was only implemented for a couple weeks and was never really tested.  It should be easy enough to go back and change things to use the new syntax.  `.bar:extend(.foo) { ... }` and `.fiz:extend(.foo) { ... }`